# List Items not changing on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4, I'm having difficulty targetting the list items on hover. I'm trying to have a default color of the text to a gray, but on hover, make the text a regular black, and on active, have the text white, bolded, with a background color for the different states of the list items.

Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <img src="resources/icons/icon-monster/iconmonstr-gear-11-48.png" alt="" class="mr-2">
            Account Settings
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item active">About You</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Education and background</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Professional Development</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Password</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Email/Notifications</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Reviews</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Privacy Settings</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--end of col-sm-4-->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/*----------------------------------------*/
/*--------SIDEBAR ACCOUNT SETTINGS---------*/
/*-----------------------------------------*/

.list-group-item.active {
  background-color: #328cc1;
  border-color: #328cc1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.list-group-item {
  color: gray;
}

.list-group-item: hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Everything works great except the list item isn't capturing the change on hover. I've tried targetting it by ul li .list-group-item: hover and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a space between : and hover. That was the problem with it.

```css
.list-group-item.active {
  background-color: #328cc1;
  border-color: #328cc1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.list-group-item {
  color: gray;
}

.list-group-item:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <img src="resources/icons/icon-monster/iconmonstr-gear-11-48.png" alt="" class="mr-2"> Account Settings
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item active">About You</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Education and background</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Professional Development</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Password</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Email/Notifications</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Reviews</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Privacy Settings</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of col-sm-4-->
```

Comment: No problem and if you want the list items to change their CSS while the mouse is clicked as well (i.e active) you can just change this to .list-group-item.active to .list-group-item:active. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that but that's one way.

Comment: @J.G.Sable Make sure to mark the answer up if it solved your query. Cheers